# Which is correct: "What is" or "What are"

Tags: grammatical-number, questions

How should I phrase "What is the first 5 digits of your home postal code" or "What are the first 5 digits of your home postal code?"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for five items, the plural "What are" is correct.

If you are asking for one thing 'What is your name?' then use singular.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about using singular versus plural, **try removing 'extra' parts of the sentence until you get just the most basic parts.**

This sentence, at its shortest, is asking

> What are the digits?

Obviously, for meaning, we need to put "postal code" back in so the person being asked knows how to answer.

> What are the digits of your postal code?

We need to specify a quantity so we get the answer we want.

> What are the first five digits of your postal code?

Without those things, the sentence has less meaning, but it's still a correct sentence.

---

It can sometimes be harder to find the subject, because there is more than one thing that seems like a candidate in the sentence. For example, with a little rearranging, you could ask:

> What is your home postal code?

or

> What is the 5-digit beginning of your home postal code?

Comment: Though of course *What is the first half of your postal code?* would be correct and would (depending on the code) have the same answer.